# Cannot read property 'getElementById' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a simple Cat Clicker app with HTML and JS, but this code keeps spitting 'Cannot read property 'getElementById' of null' error.

What's wrong with it??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Cat Clicker</title>
    <script>
      'use strict'
      var cat = document.getElementById("cat");
      var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
      var meter = 0;
      function incClick() {
        meter++;
        counter.innerHTML = meter;
      };

      cat.addEventListener('click', incClick);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="counter" >0</p>
    <img id="cat" src="img/cat1.jpg" alt="cat">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think code is running before the DOM is ready. Put the script before the closing body tag?

Comment: Or just simply use `document.getElementById('cat')` instead of `document.body.getElementById('cat')`. That might work.

Comment: @norbitrial yeah `document.body.getElementById` is undefined.

Comment: Your h1 tag has a mistake, src and alt needs to go inside

Comment: this was a mistake of my trails, I edited it already. it's supposed to be an img tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've corrected a few issues below. You need to use `document` rather than `document.body`. You need to ensure the dom has completed loading so I added a content loaded event listener.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Cat Clicker</title>
    <script>
      'use strict'
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var cat = document.getElementById("cat");
        var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
        var meter = 0;
        function incClick() {
          meter++;
          counter.innerHTML = meter;
        };

        cat.addEventListener('click', incClick);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="counter" >0</p>
    <h1 id="cat" src="img/cat1.jpg" alt="cat"></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to   include `<script>` Tags after the body of the HTML DOC or at least at the very end of your HTML content.

This is b/c how the DOM operates. It loads everything in a sequential order, thus your script it attempting to target an element which doesn't yet exist in the DOM

Comment: Yes, thank you. It works now. I totally forgot about this DOM readiness thing

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. You are mistakenly calling `getElementById` from `document.body` where it doesn't exist. It is `document.getElementById`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Cat Clicker</title>
  <script>
    'use strict'
    var cat = document.getElementById("cat");
    var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
    var meter = 0;

    function incClick() {
      meter++;
      counter.innerHTML = meter;
    };

    cat.addEventListener('click', incClick);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="counter">0</p>
  <h1 id="cat" src="img/cat1.jpg" alt="cat"></h1>
  <!-- <p class="counter">0</p>
    <img class="cat" src="img/cat2.jpg" alt="cat"> -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The snippet might confuse things as it doesn't replicate the OP's initial code. You are correct about `document.body.getElementById`

Comment: Yes, but the snippet also fixes one of the main problems with the OPs code. Without mentioning that fix the OP will not solve their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your `script` tag after the body tag because I think the problem is that the DOM is rendering after the script runs.

And you can also use `document.getElementById` instead of `document.body.getElementById`

Answer (score 0):

just use onclick="incClick()" in your h1 tag , or u can define it as image

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Cat Clicker</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="counter">0</p>
  <h1 id="cat" src="img/cat1.jpg" alt="cat"></h1>
   <p class="counter">0</p>
    <img class="cat" src="img/cat2.jpg" alt="cat">

   <!--
       You need to put the script tag at the end of the body
       Because the document must first be created
    -->
    <script>
          'use strict'
        var cat = document.getElementById("cat");
        var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
        var meter = 0;

        function incClick() {
              meter++;
          counter.innerHTML = meter;
        };

       cat.addEventListener('click', incClick);

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```